# How can I protect scanner glass for scanography while preserving depth of field and avoiding artifacts?

Tags: depth-of-field, equipment-protection, scanning, scanner

I have recently gotten into scanography, but I have not yet found a good method to protect the scanner glass from objects that will scratch or soil it. I need to find a material that is optically neutral and thin.

I have tried acetate sheets (sold as document protectors), but they are only optically neutral for perfectly flat items, such as documents. I got some clear plastic document protectors, but they crinkle and have undesirable reflective properties. I could use glass (I do have a broken scanner lying around), but unless the glass is incredibly thin, it will cut into my depth of field, which is important to me.

So what *is* the optimal material? It needs to be optically neutral, low-reflective, not prone to wrinkling, as thin as possible, and preferably cheap and/or reusable.

Comment: You're asking for a material that doesn't exist. Any high-quality optical material of significant size will not be cheap. Non-reflective doesn't *really* exist, and coatings to reduce reflections will add to the cost. You don't mention durability and scratch resistance, but you'd probably want to add those to the list as well.

Comment: By "non-reflective" I really mean "low reflective". The acetate I bought seemed like an OK material, it's just that it is slightly rough and that is bad for anything not directly against it. Is the roughness essential for the anti-reflective properties? Is there no such thing as smooth, clear acetate scanner protector sheets?

Comment: Most people don't need to "protect" their scanners.  I wouldn't consider them "optimal", but are you looking for overhead transparency sheets?

Comment: google "clear polycarbonate sheet"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been some years since I used a scanner. But I would probably buy one 3mm glass, sand the edges to smooth them round and use it if I am scanning rocks. When scanning other objects and need sharper look, remove it.

Just be careful that the "protective layer" does not become "the weapon of doom" for your scanner.

---

I have the feeling that this extra mm will not make the images blurier, just a bit dimm, but there is a chance you have some glare.